# Поменять местами div используя только float

Tags: css, html, float

Имея консткрукцию такого вида нужно поменять местами дивы (**так, чтобы было 213 и 312)** используя только св-ва float. Дополнительные обертки не допускаются.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap oh">
    <div class="test fl">1</div>
    <div class="test fl">2</div>
    <div class="test fl">3</div>
</div>
```

**СSS**

```
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
.wrap{
 width: 30px;
}
.test{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap oh">
    <div class="test ">1</div>
    <div class="test fr">2</div>
    <div class="test fl">3</div>
</div>
```

если добавить инлайн, то тогда можно крутить баранку

```css
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
.wrap{
 width: 30px;
}
.test{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap oh">
    <div class="test ">1</div>
    <div class="test fl">2</div>
    <div class="test fr">3</div>
</div>
```

или только так, по другому обтекания не позволяют выполнить такого

```css
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
.wrap{
 width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap oh">
    <div class="test fr">1</div>
    <div class="test no">2</div>
    <div class="test fr">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
.wrap{
 width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap oh">
    <div class="test fl">1</div>
    <div class="test no">2</div>
    <div class="test fl">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: прекрасно! все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score -2):

```
.fl {float:left}
.fr {float:right}
.no {float:none}
.oh {overflow:hidden}
.wrap{
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.